# 阿: when is it pronunced 'a' when is it pronunced 'e'?

Tags: pronunciation

阿 sometimes pronounced 'a' sometimes pronounced 'e'.

I've noticed specific instances for both.

Are there any rules as to how to pronounce 阿 in different circumstances/contexts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are rules - it is **not** irregular at all.

The two different pronunciations of `阿` actually reflect different usages. The original Old Chinese pronunciation of *`ē` is for using the character as a **verb or noun***, which is what the character `阿` originally meant. In contrast, the later pronunciation of *`ā` emerged as a **particle*** with completely different meanings.

Unfortunately most people have became unfamiliar with the older usage, so that the `ē` form is usually only seen in [set phrases (成語)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu).

---

### **阿 `ē`**

1. *verb*, meaning:

   - to pander to
   - to (unjustly) side with (someone in a dispute)
2. *noun* (archaic), meaning:

   - a hill
   - a (geographical) twist/turn
   - a building
3. A surname

---

### 阿 `ā`

1. *prefix* for names or familial titles, originally meaningless but can carry connotations of:

   - familiarity
   - endearment
2. *particle* (archaic, superseded by 啊) indicating:

   - surprise
   - doubt

---

As the above shows, the two different pronunciations do not overlap in their usage.

Answer (score 4):

'e' is the older pronunciation and is used to reflect the older pronunciation in some particular words (usually more formal words), such as 阿胶 (ē jiāo, some animal gelatin), 阿房宫(ē páng gōng -- notice that 房 is pronounced páng instead of fáng), 阿谀奉承.

'a' is the modern and default pronunciation, used in translation of foreign names (e.g., Algebria - 阿尔及利亚) as well as some colloquial/informal addresses/names to express familiarity (e.g., 阿爸, 阿伯, 阿花)

You may treat 'e' as an irregular pronunciation and memorize irregular words.